# Send Outlook emails (including variables and font changes)?

Tags: html, excel, vba, email, outlook

I have VBA code that works for either sending out an Outlook email with variables, or sending out an outlook email that has font changes (bold, font, etc) but not both the variables and font changes at the same time.

this will send out "hi there":
variable = "there"
OutMail.Body = "hi " & variable

this will send out "hi there" with hi being bold and there is not bold (ignore the spaces after the left carrot):
Outmail.HTMLBody = "< b>hi < /b>there"

I wanted to send this out using a variable, but it did not work. I tried this first, but it sends out "hi" in bold, but ignores the variable.
variable = "there"
Outmail.HTMLBody = "< b>hi < /b>" & variable

Here is the complete code:

```
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object, plan_day As Date, comp_tsk As String

'define EmailAddress, CCAddress, EmailSubject
plan_day = "06/02/2015"
comp_tsk = "there"

EmailBody = "< b>Today is " & plan_day & ".< /b> Hello " & comp_tsk
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
.To = EmailAddress
.CC = CCAddress
.Subject = EmailSubject
.bodyformat = 2
.HTMLBody = EmailBody
.Send

End With
```

This will send out "Today is 06/02/2015. Hello "... everything before Hello is in bold. The word "there" is nowhere to be included.

The only thing I have found is that the .HTMLBody command seems to work with variables of the "date" type, but not the "string" type. Anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: Can you post your actual code so we can better understand what you mean?

Comment: This will send out "Today is 06/02/2015. Hello "... everything before Hello is in bold. The word "there" is nowhere to be included.

Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object, plan_day As Date, comp_tsk As String

'define EmailAddress, CCAddress, EmailSubject

plan_day = "06/02/2015"

comp_tsk = "there"

EmailBody = "< b>Today is " & plan_day & ".< /b> Hello " & comp_tsk

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail

.To = EmailAddress

.CC = CCAddress

.Subject = EmailSubject

.bodyformat = 2

.HTMLBody = EmailBody

.Send

End With

Comment: do u means like this? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851554/bold-variables-in-email-body-using-excel-visual-basic)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because you replaced the entire HTMLBody.

Try something like this to insert content into the **body** of the HTML email:

```
With OutMail
    .To = EmailAddress
    .CC = CCAddress
    .Subject = EmailSubject
    .bodyformat = 2
    Debug.Print .HTMLBody ' This is to show you what the default HTMLBody is like! Surprise about how much text by default?!
    .HTMLBody = Replace(.HTMLBody,"</body>",EmailBody & "</body>")
    .Send
End With
```

Comment: The mail was blank. Including Display just before Replace produced mail with the signature before EmailBody. Note I could not reproduce the OP's missing comp_tsk but there is a possibility this could work if as well the OP set signature "none" on new mail.

Comment: @Tyop In a HTML email, a blank looking email body is never blank in HTMLBody. It have to at least include `<html>`, `<body>`,`</body>`,`</html>`. But since most Outlook setup are different, the `<body ...>` tag varies. Alternatively, can try put some unique string in plain text body, then replace it in HTMLBody.

Comment: To see test results and the code I used see rejected edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11379638

Comment: The experiment was flawed. The OP had to be here to respond when the problem only occurs for the OP. I will try to keep this in mind setting future bonuses.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you try this? I refer to this link [Bold Variables in Email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851554/bold-variables-in-email-body-using-excel-visual-basic). Give it a try...no harm I guess because in the comment said its work. Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding about this question:

```
Dim messageoutlook as variant
messageoutlook= "< b>Today is " & plan_day & ".< /b> Hello "
messageoutlook= messageoutlook & "<b>" & comp_tsk & "</b>"

With OutMail
  .To = EmailAddress
  .CC = CCAddress
  .Subject = EmailSubject
  .bodyformat = 2
  .HTMLBody = messageoutlook
  .Send

End With
```

Comment: According to the OP "The word "there" is nowhere to be included". I do not have this problem so I cannot say whether manipulating comp_tsk like this has an impact. Nevertheless, I will choose an answer for the bounty before it expires.